# Android:ScrollView will not scroll at all

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

Here is my code, I have looked at and tried all of the solutions that other people were given and still it does not scroll? Nothing happens when I try to scroll though the ScrollView. I also tried replacing the ScrollView with 'android:scrollbars = "horizontal"'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bgstardust"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"
        style="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        tools:context="com.example.cs_gage.brickbreaker.BackgroundActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_outline_dark"
                        android:background="@drawable/bgblackdesign"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_outline_dark"
                        android:background="@drawable/bgdarksquares"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

                    ...

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use horizontal ScrollView, you have set android:orientation="horizontal" to linear layout

Comment: y have u added weights ??? .... and does your scroll items occupy less space then they require,if they have enough display space,whats the purpose of scroll

Comment: Is the above code is complete??

Comment: use HorizontalScrollView instead of ScrollView

Comment: First make `RelativeLayout` height to `0dp` and add `android:fillViewPort="true"` for `ScrollView`.

Comment: @Pravin got it. I just had to use the HorizontalScrollView, also sorry it wouldnt let me post the question with so much code so i took out the RelativeLayout right before the other RelativeLayout. That is why I had weights.

Comment: @GageHafl Its ok brother, ping here if issue is not resolved